# Poll Process CPU in Powershell over time

Tags: powershell, iis

Very new to powershell, so here it goes.

So the end goal is: Every ten seconds, check if an IIS process is over a certain CPU usage. If it sustains above a certain level for more than a minute, reset it.

I understand that  Get-Counter "\Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time" will give me the number I need.

How would I go about checking it every 10 seconds? The logic for comparing to previous checks I think I can manage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll contribute an answer. I will use a While loop as well, but formatted a bit differently.

```
$Countdown = 0
While((Get-Counter "\Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time"|sort -Descending |Select -First 1) -gt <target CPU usage>){
    $Countdown+=10
    if($countdown -gt 60){
        Reset IIS
        $Countdown = 0
    }
    start-sleep 10
}
```

Then schedule it to run once a minute, or every 5 minutes, or whatever. If it runs and something is over your target usage it will continue to run until it gets to a minute, then it does whatever you need to reset, and set $countdown back to 0. I put the sleep after the reset, so if the usage shoots right back up it will continue to run and will reset after a minute again.

Comment: I'm curious, does sort descending provide any benefit here?

Comment: I, uh, are you only getting one process? Sorry, I was assuming there would be multiple responses, and was just trying to get the highest one. If there is only 1 response from that Get-Counter then you can skip the Sort and Select pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a script like this:

```
While (1){

#Checking Code
Get-Counter "\Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time"

#Sleep for 10 seconds
Sleep 10

}
```

Or the "better" option is to have a scheduled task that runs every minute or so.